# Select a Radio Button in Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, radio-button, response

I have an ajax response that replaces the contents in a div.  The response is this:

```
<input onchange="switch(this.value)" value="val" id="code" checked="checked" type="radio" name="code" />
```

The radio button shows up just fine, however, it is not checked.  Any ideas why?

Comment: what browser is this tested in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a radio button, not a checkbox and maybe another radio button in the same group (i.e. with the same 'name') is already checked.

Comment: ha oops sorry for the title, but no that response replaces all other radios on this particular page

Comment: somehow the returned response was in a hidden div and there was another radio like you said.

Comment: i think i can modestly ask for a clairvoyance badge for that one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write any code for onclick. The default behavior of radio button is to change its state on click. Also `value='val'` attribute. I guess it's messing up with checked attribute.